# Oracle How to select a set of latest entries

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime, select, unique

I have an Oracle table that looks like below:

```
URL   SIZE   MODDATE     MODTIME
AAA   100    24-OCT-14   10:00:00
AAA   100    24-OCT-14   09:00:00
AAA   100    23-OCT-14   08:00:00
BBB   100    24-OCT-14   10:00:00
BBB   100    24-OCT-14   09:00:00
BBB   100    23-OCT-14   08:00:00
CCC   100    24-OCT-14   10:00:00
CCC   100    24-OCT-14   09:00:00
CCC   100    23-OCT-14   08:00:00
```

I need to get the latest data for each row based on MODDATE & MODTIME. So the result would look like this:

```
URL   SIZE   MODDATE     MODTIME
AAA   100    24-OCT-14   10:00:00
BBB   100    24-OCT-14   10:00:00
CCC   100    24-OCT-14   10:00:00
```

How would the SELECT look like (Oracle)?

Thank you kindly for your help!

Comment: Which data types are MODDATE and MODTIME? Are they strings? Then it will be difficult, "APR" will come before "JAN". Are tey `DATE` types? If yes, why do you have 2 columns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `ROW_NUMBER` analytic function

```
SELECT "URL", "SIZE", "MODDATE", "MODTIME"
FROM
(
SELECT "URL", "SIZE", "MODDATE", "MODTIME",
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY "URL" order by "MODDATE" desc, "MODTIME" desc) as seq
FROM Table1
) T
Where T.seq =1
```

Comment: Is there a way to create an index to speed up the query? it takes about 20-30 secs on 600k rows.

Comment: @Brongadier, explain plan would give you more details, the index might be required on URL column, but if it is string, then it would take much longer space, so you can have a check sum field for url and index it.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table
WHERE MODDATE IN (SELECT max(MODDATE) FROM table)
ORDER BY MODTIME
```

Comment: This won't work because I'll have all AAA, BBB, & CCC rows repeating. There should only be 3.

Comment: if you 'correlate' the sub-query with the 'outer' 'url' as well then it should return the expected result. untested.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming column MODDATE is a `DATE` data type and MODTIME is a string.

```
select DISTINCT URL, SIZE,
   LAST_VALUE(MODDATE) OVER (PARTITION BY URL, SIZE ORDER BY MODDATE, MODTIME) as MODDATE,
   LAST_VALUE(MODTIME) OVER (PARTITION BY URL, SIZE ORDER BY MODDATE, MODTIME) as MODTIME
from your_table;
```